# Java メソッド 引数 戻り値

Tags: java

#### 前提・実現したいこと

変数 int num にシステムから入力値が与えられています。
メソッドを作成し、mainにてそのメソッドを呼出し、戻り値の要素を全て表示する。
その際、0番目の要素は表示しないように処理を実装する。
また、戻り値がnullだった場合、要素の出力ではなく「指定されたIDは見つかりません」と出力する。
メソッドの呼出しの際、実引数は変数 int num を設定する。

**入力値**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**期待値**

```
あいうえお
かきくけこ
さしすせそ
```

**メソッドの内容**

```
{"1","あ","い","うえお"}
{"2","か","き","くけこ"}
{"3","さ","し","すせそ"}
```

上記の要素を持つ静的配列変数を3つ宣言する。
数値型引数をString型変数に型変換する。
各配列の0番目の値とString型に変換した引数を比較し、比較して一致した場合、一致した配列変数を戻り値とする。
どの配列とも一致しなかった場合、nullを戻り値とする。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

> java.lang.NullPointerException

と表示される。
nullが返ってきた際の処理がないことが原因だと思うのですが、色々調べてコードを書いてみましたがうまく処理することが出来ませんでした。
助言を頂けると幸いです。

#### ソースコード

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scan.next();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
    String[] fuga = getUserProfile(num);
      for (int i = 1; i < fuga.length; i++){
        if (fuga[i] != null){
          System.out.println(fuga[i]);
        }else{
          System.out.println("指定されたIDは見つかりません");
        }
      }
  }
  static String[] getUserProfile(int num){
    String[] data1 = {"1","あ","い","うえお"};
    String[] data2 = {"2","か","き","くけこ"};
    String[] data3 = {"3","さ","し","すせそ"};
    String hoge = Integer.toString(num);
      if(data1[0] == hoge){
        return data1;
      }else if(data2[0] == hoge){
        return data2;
      }else if(data3[0] == hoge){
        return data3;
      }else{
        return null;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

文字列の比較に`==`を使っているからですね。全ての

```java
 == hoge
```

を

```java
.equals(hoge)
```

に置換すれば、意図した動作をすると思います。ただし、この修正をした後も1、2、3以外の数値を入力すれば、以下の条件に入るのでNPEが発生します。

```java
      }else{
        return null;
```

それ以外にも直した方がいい箇所はいくつかあります。

Comment: 無事解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したら、回答を[承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)しておいて下さい。

Answer (score 0):

くどい言い方かもしれませんが、まずどのステップでエラーになっているか、またnumに何を入力したか書いたほうがいいと思います。そのほうが説明しやすいかと思います。
その上でですが、

```
for (int i = 1; i < fuga.length; i++){
```

で 「fuga」はNULLになっているかと思いますのでlengthを参照できません。その手前のステップでNULLの場合は

```
System.out.println("指定されたIDは見つかりません");
```

としてあげれば期待する動作になるかと思います。